# Do we have a Trishati Namavali for Varahi?

Tags: tantra, resource, sri-vidya, matrika

Do we have Trishathi Namavali (a stotra consisting of 300 names) for [Varahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varahi)? I heard it's there in "Uddamaresha Tantra" (not Uddamareshvara Tantra). If anyone can provide any information it will be very useful.