# Is Varahi Devi Trishati available? I want soft copy

Tags: mantras, resource, stotra, sri-vidya

I search for "Sri Varahi Devi Trishati", either stotra or namavali
"Varahi Devi Trishati 300 names" in any language.

I search in telugu, hindi, sanskrit, english, tamil or what ever language.

Could any one help me?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22324/do-we-have-a-trishati-namavali-for-varahi

Comment: Do u know in which scripture it is found? @Sai